# Finding a single value among multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a circumstance where I need to determine if a single value exists in one of up to 20 different columns for a given user record, but they are not position-specific.
So, each user has 1 or more applications they are responsible for maintaining and when a particular application is entered, the query would look in all 20 columns in the users' record for that application value.
What I DONT want to do is something like this:

```
Select * from users u
where 
u.app1 = 'appl1' or u.app2 = 'appl1' or u.app3 = 'appl1' or... u.app20 = 'appl1'
```

Is there a way to simplify the where clause to something like

```
where u.app* = 'appl1'
```

Comment: Did you design this table? If you did, please read up on normalization principles. You **should not** have 20 columns

Comment: FreshPrince - no I did not and agree completely with your assessment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot simplify the `where` clause that way.  However you can use `in`:

```
Select *
from users u
where 'appl1' in (u.app1, u.app2, u.app3,  . . . u.app20)
```

In general, such repeated columns are an example of bad database design.  You should have another table that has one row per user/app combinations (say `UserApps`).  With such a table, your query would be much simpler.

Comment: Could be a case of a legacy system, where whoever decided the design did a lousy job of it.  I've been stuck maintaining a system like that before, and believe me it's no fun.

Comment: Thanks - That works for me.  I appreciate the assistance!

Comment: user2366842, you hit the nail on the head!  That is the exact situation!